# Compare two columns in excel & Highlight

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, excel-2010

[image]

I am comparing column A and B. I want to highlight the cells if any duplicate value is found in the other column. So in the above example ABC will not get highlighted since there is no such string in column B, but DEF will get highlighted since it is available in both.

Can someone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional formatting with a custom formula:

"=SUMPRODUCT(--(B2 = $C$2:$C$5))"

you'll need a reciprocal formula for the other range

[conditional formatting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uiTi.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. Select the entire data set.
2. Go to Home tab.
3. Click  **Conditional Formatting** option.
4. Select Highlight Cell Rules ->  **Duplicate Values** option
5. Make sure **Duplicate** is selected and choose your format in the "Duplicate Values" dialog box.

Comment: But when i use this, ABC also will get highlighted. I wanted only the cells to be highlighted if it is found in both the columns

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
Sub CompareColumns()
Dim aRng, bRng As Range
Set aRng = Range("A2:A5")
Set bRng = Range("B2:B5")

For Each aCell In aRng
    For Each bCell In bRng
        If aCell Is Nothing Or bCell Is Nothing Then
        ElseIf aCell.Text = bCell.Text Then
            bCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
        End If
    Next bCell
Next aCell

End Sub
```

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]